# Remove node or children based on another child

Tags: xslt, wix, xslt-2.0

I'm using Wix Head to harvest my output directory with some third-party dependencies, but still trying to wrap my head around XSLT transformations.

What I have roughly have:

```
<Wix>
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="1">
        <File Source="Valid.dll"/>
        <RegistryValue />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="2">
        <File Source="Valid.pdb"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="3">
        <File Source="XML.dll"/>
        <RegistryValue />
        <RegistryValue />
        <RegistryValue />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef> 
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="Published">
      <Component Id="1" />
      <Component Id="2" />
      <Component Id="3" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What I want:

```
<Wix>
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER>
      <Component Id="1">
        <File Source="Valid.dll"/>
        <RegistryValue />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="3">
        <File Source="XML.dll"/>
      </Component>
    <DirectoryRef> 
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="Published">
      <Component Id="1" />
      <Component Id="3" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My XSLT so far but the templates don't apply to each other. They do their own thing. They are in wix namespace but I simplified it for this question.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="pdbs" match="Component[contains(File/@Source, 'pdb')]" use="@Id"/>
    <xsl:key name="unneededRegistry" match="Component[not(contains(File/@Source, 'Valid'))]" use="@Id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove PDBs -->
    <xsl:template match="*[self::Component or self::ComponentRef][key('pdbs',@Id']"/>

    <!-- Remove everything but file in non-core dlls -->
    <xsl:template match="Component[key('unneededRegistry',@Id)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-template select="@*|File"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I feel like I'm close to getting it but I've tried so much to no avail.
I need to remove all the components with pdb in the file and remove all nodes that aren't File on the Valid ones.

Comment: Your input XML is not well-formed, as you have an opening `<DirectoryRef>`. I am guessing this is because you have tried to simplify your XML for the question. However, have you also edited out a `xmlns="...."` on the root `wix` element? If so, this is a "default namespace" and could be of importance to your question if your XSLT is not handling that namespace. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. A simplification. It's just summary of a 40k line wxs file. I can't copy paste due to air-gapped computer.

All the templates work, they just don't chain like I want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a modified style sheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="pdbs" match="Component[contains(File/@Source, 'pdb')]" use="@Id"/>
    <!-- I have removed this key
    <xsl:key name="unneededRegistry" match="Component[not(contains(File/@Source, 'Valid'))]" use="@Id"/>
    -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove PDBs,
         have included a predicate here instead of a key
    -->
    <xsl:template match="*[self::Component or self::ComponentRef]
        [contains(File/@Source, 'pdb')]"/>

    <!-- Remove everything but file in non-core dlls,
         have included a predicate here instead of a key
    -->
    <xsl:template match="DirectoryRef/Component[not(contains(File/@Source, 'Valid'))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|File"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- added a rule here to delete target Component nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="ComponentGroup/Component[key('pdbs', @Id)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpN).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about processing the ComponentRef and DirectoryRef separately!